# Measure of subsets in $\mathbb S^d$ defined by multiplicities of real roots

Tags: polynomials, measurable-functions

We associate to an element $\mathbf x=(x_0,\ldots,x_d)$
of the real unit sphere $\mathbb S^d=\lbrace (x_0,\ldots,x_d)\in\mathbb R^{d+1},\
x_0^2+\dots+x_d^2=1\rbrace$ the number $\mu(\mathbf x)$ of real roots of the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^d x_it^i$ in $\mathbb R[t]$.
The preimage $\mu^{-1}(n)$ of a natural integer $n\geq 0$ has strictly positive measure if and only if $n\leq d$ and $n$
has the same parity as $d$.

*Can the measure (with respect to the uniform probability measure on $\mathbb S^d$) of these preimages be computed?* (I suspect that this question and perhaps even an answer is known.)

Remarks: The uniform (Lebesgue) measure on $\mathbb S^d$ is perhaps not the best for this problem. Another natural candidat (on a slightly different set of polynomials) is to consider $t^d+\sum x_it^i$ with $(x_0,\ldots,x_{d-1})$ in the $d$-dimensional unit $l_1$-ball defined by $-1\leq x_i\leq 1$.

For $d=2$, the preimage of $2$ has strictly larger measure than the preimage of $0$. It would be interesting to know the "most frequent"
value of $\mu$ for large $d$.